What is the analogue of $N_J$ and $[X,Y] \mod F$ for almost symplectic forms $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$?
Given an almost complex structure $J: TM \to TM$
$$
N_J: \Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TM),
$$
$$
N_J(X,Y) = [X,Y] + J([JX,Y] + [X,JY]) - [JX,JY]
$$
gives rise to a 2-form with coefficients
$$
N_J \in \Omega^2(M, TM).
$$
Given a distribution $F \subset TM$
$$
\text{Curv}_F: \Gamma(F) \times \Gamma(F) \to \Gamma(\nu),
$$
$$
\text{Curv}_F(X,Y) = [X,Y] \mod F
$$
gives rise to a section
$$
\text{Curv}_F \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 F^* \otimes \nu).
$$
My question is, for almost symplectic forms $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$, what is the analogue of $N_J$ and $\text{Curv}_F$ ?
Here $F$ is a $p$-dimensional distribution on an $m$-dimensional manifold, $F \subset TM$ The normal bundle of $F$ is defined as the quotient bundle:
$\nu := TM/F$. Any tangent vector on $M$ induces an element of $\nu$, and, any vector field $X$ on $M$ induces a section of $\nu$ (the class of $X$ in the quotient), which is denoted $ X \mod F \in \Gamma(\nu) $
Two sections of $\nu$ ,  $X \mod F$ and $X' \mod F$, coincide iff $X - X' \in \Gamma(F)$.

I don't understand. Isn't the question simply whether $\omega$ is a closed $2$-form?

@TedShifrin I thought I had to define something  analogous to $N_J$ that becomes 0 when one considering almost symplectic forms, so you are suggesting to it would be $d\omega$?

Yes, as it’s not really an analogous integrability situation.

@TedShifrin But why is $d\omega$ an analogue to both $N_J$ and $Cur_F$ ? I admit I don't understand  $Cur_F$ very well. $d\omega $ is a three-form, so it receives 3 sections an outputs a number. Don't we need something  that receives 2 sections and outputs another section as $N_J$ and $Cur_F$?

I don’t see that your question is meaningful. What makes you think the mathematical circumstances are similar? Where did this question come from? I’m also not sure why the obstruction $\text{Curv}_F$ is named curvature; an integrable distribution has zero curvature in what sense? In my 50 years as a geometer, I’ve not seen this particular definition formalized in this way.

@TedShifrin The question in the post is part of a exercise, question 1 was prove that N_J gives rise to a 2-form, question 2 that F gives rise to a section, question 3 is exactly as posted.  Reference https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~crain101/DG-2016/chapter1.pdf although it is not there.

@TedShifrin Here a more recent version https://file.io/3QTyUY5sSfb9. on page 233 it is defined curv

I went down the rabbit hole with Crainic's book (of which you linked the first chapter only). I did not find the exercise, but he certainly discusses how this all fits in a big picture in his chapter on $G$-structures. And he makes it clear that saying $\omega$ is closed is the analogous integrability condition.

@TedShifrin The exercise is not there, I was hoping it would clear up why Curv is named curvature and why $d\omega$ is the analogous to Curv

The analogue of the vanishing condition is simply $d\omega=0$. The analogous mapping is $\omega\mapsto d\omega$, i.e. the exterior derivative. To see why this is so, one should study generalised complex geometry, which encompasses both symplectic and complex geometry (and foliated geometry). In particular, every generalised complex structure on a manifold can be expressed as a complex Dirac structure, which is a sub-bundle $L\subseteq (TM\oplus T^*M)\otimes\mathbb{C}$ satisfying certain constraints. One can show that such structures are characterised by sections $\varepsilon\in\wedge^2 E^*$ for some $E\subseteq TM$. In the cited reference, it is proved that an almost generalised complex structure is integrable if and only if
$$d_L\varepsilon = 0\text{ and }\text{pr}_{TM}(L)\subseteq TM\text{ is involutive}$$
When $L$ comes from a symplectic structure, then $L=\{X-i\iota_X\omega\mid X\in TM\otimes\mathbb{C}\}$, and $\varepsilon=i\omega$, so this equation reduces to $d\omega=0$. This is one extreme of the spectrum of generalised complex structures, i.e. symplectic structures.
In case of an almost complex structure, $J$, one takes $L=TM^{0,1}\oplus T^*M^{1,0}$. It can be shown (proposition 3.27 and example 3.34) that integrability of $L$ is equivalent to the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor.
Distributions $F\subseteq TM$ are also subsumed by generalised complex geometry (example 3.32).

How come the analogue is an equation/condition, while the others are just maps?

The analogue of the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor is $d\omega=0$. The analogous "map" is the exterior derivative.

and how is it also an analogue of Curv?

You're going to have to read the paper for that and understand the material, it's not just a triviality that I can explain in a comment.
